# Adding HTTPHandler using SPWebConfigModification

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss

I'm using the following code to add few httpHandlers (for Telerik controls) through the following code.

```
            SPWebConfigModification webConfig = null;

            webConfig = new SPWebConfigModification();
            webConfig.Owner = featureID;
            webConfig.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            webConfig.Path = "/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers";
            webConfig.Name = "add[@path='Telerik.ReportViewer.axd']";
            webConfig.Value = "<add verb=\"*\" path=\"Telerik.ReportViewer.axd\" type = \"Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=4.2.10.1110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be\" />";
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(webConfig);

            webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApp.Update();

            webConfig = new SPWebConfigModification();
            webConfig.Owner = featureID;
            webConfig.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            webConfig.Path = "/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers";
            webConfig.Name = "add[@path='ChartImage.axd']";
            webConfig.Value = "<add path=\"ChartImage.axd\" verb=\"*\" type=\"Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2010.2.826.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4\" validate=\"false\" />";
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(webConfig);

            webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApp.Update();

            webConfig = new SPWebConfigModification();
            webConfig.Owner = featureID;
            webConfig.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            webConfig.Path = "/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers";
            webConfig.Name = "add[@path='Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd']";
            webConfig.Value = "<add path=\"Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd\" verb=\"*\" type=\"Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2010.2.826.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4\" validate=\"false\"/>";
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(webConfig);

            webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApp.Update();

            webConfig = new SPWebConfigModification();
            webConfig.Owner = featureID;
            webConfig.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            webConfig.Path = "/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers";
            webConfig.Name = "remove[@path='Telerik.ReportViewer.axd']";
            webConfig.Value = "<add verb=\"*\" path=\"Telerik.ReportViewer.axd\" type = \"Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=4.2.10.1110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be\" />";
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(webConfig);

            webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApp.Update();

            webConfig = new SPWebConfigModification();
            webConfig.Owner = featureID;
            webConfig.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            webConfig.Path = "/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers";
            webConfig.Name = "remove[@path='Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*']";
            webConfig.Value = "<add name=\"Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*\" path=\"Telerik.ReportViewer.axd\" verb=\"*\" type=\"Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=4.2.10.1110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be\" preCondition=\"integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0\" />";
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(webConfig);

            webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApp.Update();
```

But I'm getting the error as

> '' is an invalid expression.

That is not very detailed. Any ideas?

Comment: In what line the exception occurs?

Comment: Ideas - yeah, check the line number for the exception. Or, attach visual studio to the W3WP processes, and then try activating your feature again.

Comment: The error was in the line where I apply the web configuration changes using ApplyWebConfigModifications().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie, I've fixed it. The error was appearing on `ApplyWebConfigModifcations()` line. It was holding some previous erroneous web.config change entries. Calling

```
webApp.WebConfigModifications.Clear()
```

fixed the issue.